# What is the max amount of achievements I can get by performing any one action?

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2

As most are probably aware, Team Fortress 2 has a ton of achievements, most of which are seemingly unrelated to each other. But I've been curious about this for a long time.

If I was a new player, what is one action I could perform that would net the most amount of achievements instantly?

For example, I came up with that if I was a spy, disguised as a medic, who killed that medic (who was healing me) with a backstab while he had an Ubercharge ready and also got Revenge on him at the same time, I would get the Achievements "*Dr. Nooooo*", "*FYI I am a Spy*", "*Come in from the Cold*", "*Identity Theft*", and "*Insurance Fraud*", all at the same time. Is there anything else more advanced than this?

Comment: Cross-reference: This same question [has been discussed](http://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/2j7lbq/the_largest_amount_of_achievements_you_can_get_in/) on Reddit TF2, [more than once](http://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/1r2lgo/experimentmaximum_achievements/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The Soldier can put together a pretty good chunk - though as you might expect, it's rather difficult to set up:

- Be on a server where Halloween mode is on for any reason.
- The map is Dustbowl or Gravel Pit.
- Have a crowd of enemies:

  1. A Pyro, who:

     - Reflected one of your rockets recently, and
     - has set you on fire
  2. A Demoman,

     - Wearing a Gibus
     - and Pyrovision Goggles
     - whom you're one kill away from dominating
  3. A Sniper

     - with a Balloonicorn
     - who's dominating you
  4. A Spy, who:

     - just stabbed one of your teammates
     - is disguised as you
  5. A fifth enemy, with 270 health or less.
- These enemies are all capping the first point during overtime.
- These enemies have all recently damaged the Medic healing you.

Then:

1. The Medic pops Kritz on you
2. You fire a crit rocket
3. The Sniper kills you
4. Your crocket kills all of your enemies, which wins your team the game.

As a result of this action you claim:

- Your 1000th Soldier kill
- 500th Demoman kill
- 79th Balloonicorn-owner kill
- 30th point defense
- 20th kill while on fire
- 20th game win
- 10th top-3 score for MVP
- 5th revenge kill
- 1st domination on people wearing:

  1. A Gibus
  2. Pyrovison Goggles
- 1st time ever completing a full round on either one of Dustbowl/Gravel Pit (having now played full rounds on all of 2Fort, Dustbowl, Granary, Gravel Pit, Hydro, and cp_Well).

By doing this, you get the following achievements:

- *A Fresh Pair of Eyes*
- *Backdraft Dodger*
- *Costume Contest*
- *Dynasty*
- *Frags of our Fathers*
- *Ghastly Gibus Grab*
- *Hamburger Hill*
- *Impenetrable Defense* or *Impossible Defense* (depends on map)
- *Medals of Honor*
- *Mutually Assured Destruction*
- *Nemesis*
- *Out, Damned Scot!*
- *Semper Fry*
- **S*M*A*S*H**
- *The Great Deflate*
- *Tri-Splatteral Damage*
- *War Crime and Punishment*
- *War Crime Spybunal*
- *World Traveler*
- One (if not two!) of the Soldier milestone achivements

This gives you a total of **19+2**.

Comment: Damn, 21, nice!  That's definitely way more than what I had.

Comment: The concept and bundling is majestic.

Comment: If you've previously killed a few people in the same life, and have never gone more than 4 kills without dying up that point, you could also fit in *Hard to Kill*.

Comment: On reflection, you could also fit in *Riftwalker*, by teleporting to the point, and *Hardcore*, I think, if you only ever played as Soldier, so that your 1000th kill as Solder is your 1000th overall.

Answer (score 14):

I think I've found another one:

You are a Spy disguised as an enemy Spy backstabbing that same Spy who is

- On your friends list
- Has his revolver out
- Is dominating 3 of your teammates
- Is also disguised as a Spy
- Is equipping the Balloonicorn and is your 79th Balloonicorn victim

You get Revenge on that Spy and get your 1000th stab on top of a Control Point that just became available because the other spy captured it while being healed by a medic and you being covered in Jarate and after having that enemy spy trigger your Dead Ringer and you exiting a teleporter and having 4 prior spy achievements, and this kill is your 5th kill in a row without dying, gives you:

- Come in from the Cold (revenge)
- High Value Target (stab someone with 3 dominations)
- Spymaster (1000 stabs)
- Agent Provacateur (stab 10 friends)
- Identity Theft (stab the guy you are disguised as)
- A Cut Above (kill a revolver-wielding spy with your knife)
- Insurance Fraud (get a backstab while an enemy medic heals you)
- Sleeps Agent (kill the guy that triggered your DR within 20 seconds)
- On Her Majesty's Secret Surface (start capping a point as soon as it becomes available)
- Counter Espionage (backstab a disguised spy)
- Wetwork (kill someone while jarated)
- Point Breaker
- Milestone 1
- Milestone 2
- Milestone 3
- Costume Contest (kill a spy disguised as your current class)
- Nemesis (5 revenge kills)
- Riftwalker (get a kill shortly after exiting a tele)
- Hard to kill (5 kills in a row without dying)
- Hardcore (get 1000 total kills)
- The great deflate (kill 79 people with balloonicorns)

Total achievements from 1 stab: 21 achievements

Answer (score 3):

Apparently 25 is possible as Sniper, courtesy of [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/2j7lbq/the_largest_amount_of_achievements_you_can_get_in/cl9t3vb):

**Setup**

You must have exactly:

- 4 Sniper achievements
- 999 kills (all Sniper)
- 1 prior Domination
- 78 Balloonicorn kills
- 24 parachute headshots
- 9 Sniper headshots
- 4 prior Revenge kills

**Equipment**

- Pyrovision goggles
- The Machina
- The Razorback

**Action time!**

1. Take a teleporter
2. Take a fully-charged shot
3. Your fully charged shot must kill all of the following:

   - A sniper,

     - Whom you've killed 3 times
     - Who is wearing

       - Pyrovision
       - A Balloonicorn
   - A Spy,

     - Who recently tried to backstab you
     - who is now cloaked
   - A second Spy who just uncloaked
   - A Demoman

     - Who is parachuting with the Base Jumper, following a sticky jump
     - With a headshot
   - A second Demoman

     - Who is charging towards you
     - Who is also dominating you
   - A Medic

     - With full Uber
   - A Scout

     - During a double-jump
   - A sentry gun
4. Taunt (well, who wouldn't after all that?)

**Sniper-specific Achievements**

- Australian Rules
- Be Efficient
- De-sentry-lized
- Dropped Dead
- Flight Cancelled
- Jumper Stumper
- Kill Everyone You Meet
- Not a Crazed Gunman, Dad
- Parting Shot
- Self-destruct Sequence
- Shock Treatment
- Shoot the Breeze
- Socket to Him
- The Last Wave
- Triple Prey
- Überectomy
- Sniper Milestone 1

**General achievements**

- Nemesis
- Riftwalker
- The Great Deflate
- Hardcore
- Hard to Kill
- Emergency Brake
- BFF²
- A Fresh Pair of Eyes

**Total: 25 achievements**